# how to save jtextfield value to a .txt file as a log?

Tags: java, file, save, jtextfield

I have a simple java shopping app with netbeans GUI, when someone presses the checkout jbutton I want to save jtextfield value to a external .txt file. everytime someone initiate the checkout option I want to save every transaction value to a .txt file with time. how can I do this ?

Comment: Post relevant code here. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

First get the text value of your `JTextField` by,

```
JTextField textField = ...; //
String text = textField.getText();
```

Then pass the value to the `writeToFile` method like below,

```
writeToFile(text);
```

**writeToFile** method

```
void writeToFile(String fileName, String text) throws Exception {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
   out.write(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this Code

```
String content = textFieldName.getText();    //step1: get the content of the textfield

    try {

                File file = new File("/users/mkyong/filename.txt");

                // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(content);    //step2: write it
                bw.close();

                System.out.println("Done");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```